# column "d.discount_amount" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: mysql

I  have written this query to find the payment using two different table ,

```
SELECT (SUM(o_p.price) - d.discount_amount) as payment
FROM order_products as o_p
LEFT JOIN discounts as d  ON O_p.order_id = d.order_id
GROUP BY o_p.order_id
```

It shows an error column "d.discount_amount" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT o_p.order_id, (SUM(price) - d.discount_amount) as pay...

9:23 PM

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.sm - t2.discount_amount
  from (
select t1.order_id,
       sum(t1.price) sm
  from order_products t1
 order by t1.order_id) t1 left join discounts t2 on t1.order_id = t2.order_id
```

Comment: Please add details around what's the mistake the original poster has done and how your answer can help him/her.

Comment: As the exception report says, the query list must all be included in the groupby clause, so you need to change the word order.
The answer is not unique, I guess what you might want to write is this, but it is easy for novices to make mistakes on the above, I do not recommend

Comment: select t1.order_id,
    sum(t1.price) - ifnull(t2.discount_amount, 0)
  from order_products t1 left join discounts t2 on t1.order_id = t2.order_id
 group by t1.order_id, t2.discount_amount
;

Comment: You did a good job in posting the actual answer that would work. It would help the author as well as other community members when going through this post, when you add details around the what's the error (like you added details in the comment on what you have inferred from the error report) and how the solution can help solving it.